# Why Won't My Mail Application Work (RunTime Error)?

Tags: android, email, runtime-error

I have been working on getting a mail app to work from a tutorial at

http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android

However I keep getting a run time error every time I try to run it. I am new to android programming and I am not quite sure how to read the logcat errors so I throw myself at the mercy of the internet, please help.

I have the internet permission correctly set up, and activation.jar, mail.jar, and additional.jar are included in the project and have a build path set up to it.

Main Code

```
 package com.dummies.android.MailTest;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MailTestActivity extends Activity 
 {
private Button mButton;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send); 
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    { 
      public void onClick(View view) 
      { 
        Mail m = new Mail("********.com", "********"); 

        String[] toArr = {"*******@gmail.com"}; 
        m.setTo(toArr); 
        m.setFrom("*********.com"); 
        m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an        Android device."); 
        m.setBody("Email body."); 

        try { 
          //m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation"); 

          if(m.send()) { 
            Toast.makeText(MailTestActivity.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
          } else { 
            Toast.makeText(MailTestActivity.this, "Email was not sent.",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
          } 
        } catch(Exception e) { 
          //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
          Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
        } 
      } 
    }); 
  } 
}
```

Mail Class

```
 package com.dummies.android.MailTest;

 import java.util.Date; 
 import java.util.Properties; 
 import javax.activation.CommandMap; 
 import javax.activation.DataHandler; 
 import javax.activation.DataSource;  
 import javax.activation.FileDataSource; 
 import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap; 
 import javax.mail.BodyPart; 
 import javax.mail.Multipart; 
 import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication; 
 import javax.mail.Session; 
 import javax.mail.Transport; 
 import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress; 
 import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart; 
 import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage; 
 import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart; 


 public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
 private String _user; 
 private String _pass; 

 private String[] _to; 
 private String _from; 

 private String _port; 
 private String _sport; 

 private String _host; 

 private String _subject; 
 private String _body; 

 private boolean _auth; 

 private boolean _debuggable; 

 private Multipart _multipart; 


 public Mail() { 
  _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
  _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
  _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

  _user = ""; // username 
  _pass = ""; // password 
  _from = ""; // email sent from 
  _subject = ""; // email subject 
  _body = ""; // email body 

  _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
  _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

  _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

   // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the    multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
   MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
   mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
   mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
   mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content- handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
   mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
   mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
   CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
   } 

  public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
  this(); 

  _user = user; 
  _pass = pass; 
 } 

 public Mail(EditText user, EditText pass) 
 {
  _userE = user; 
  _passE = pass;
 }

 public boolean send() throws Exception { 
 Properties props = _setProperties(); 

 if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
  Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

  MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

  msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

  InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
  for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
    addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
  } 
    msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

  msg.setSubject(_subject); 
  msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

  // setup message body 
  BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
  messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
  _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

  // Put parts in message 
  msg.setContent(_multipart); 

  // send email 
  Transport.send(msg); 

  return true; 
  } else { 
   return false; 
  }  
  } 

 public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
  BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
 DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
 messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
 messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

 _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
 } 

 @Override 
 public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
 return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
 } 

private Properties _setProperties() { 
Properties props = new Properties(); 

props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

if(_debuggable) { 
  props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
} 

if(_auth) { 
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
} 

props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

return props; 
 } 

 // the getters and setters 
 public String getBody() { 
 return _body; 
 } 

 public void setBody(String _body) { 
  this._body = _body; 
 } 

 public void setSubject(String _subject) 
 { 
    this._subject = _subject; 
 }

 public void setFrom(String _from) 
 { 
    this._from = _from; 
 }

 public void setTo(String[] _to) 
 { 
    this._to = _to; 
 }

 // more of the getters and setters ….. 
 }
```

and finally here is my logcat

```
06-21 12:42:32.049: E/dalvikvm(1079): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
06-21 12:42:32.859: E/dalvikvm(1079): Could not find class 'com.dummies.android.MailTest.Mail', referenced from method com.dummies.android.MailTest.MailTestActivity$1.onClick
06-21 12:42:36.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1079): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 12:42:36.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1079): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.dummies.android.MailTest.Mail
06-21 12:42:36.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at com.dummies.android.MailTest.MailTestActivity$1.onClick(MailTestActivity.java:30)
06-21 12:42:36.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
06-21 12:42:36.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
06-21 12:42:36.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-21 12:42:36.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-21 12:42:36.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-21 12:42:36.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-21 12:42:36.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 12:42:36.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-21 12:42:36.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-21 12:42:36.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-21 12:42:36.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT: With no edits being made to my code, I am not getting a NoClassDefFoundError instead. Both classes were added straight to the src folder under the package, neither code is externally added. So why am I getting this error now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be more simplistic than I thought, the tutorial I started with was an older one. I just had to change the name of the lib folder to libs and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

> 06-21 12:42:32.859: E/dalvikvm(1079): **Could not find** class
>   '*com.dummies.android.MailTest.Mail*', **referenced from** method
>   *com.dummies.android.MailTest.MailTestActivity$1.onClick*

This error should be self-explanatory enough.
Make sure you have all your classes at the right place.

Comment: I think they are in the right places, both classes are within the src folder, and within the same package. That should be the correct place for the classes, should it not?

Answer (score 0):

There might be an error with Android SDK, I got same error with SDK package 18 so I revert back to SDK package 16 and it worked for me.

Comment: Is there no other way? I know I am new to this, but I would rather not go through the trouble of installing an older version and risk messing up some other projects I am working on.

Comment: Currently there is know AFAIK. The issue is reported and it will be resolved soon, but currently there is no other solution.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, I ended up resolving it. I was using an older tutorial as a guide, all I had to do was rename my lib folder to libs and it worked fine.